# Dynamic Link Tracking with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

For tracking and attribution purposes we need to add tracking parameters for each of our links pointing to any of our websites.

For example:
`http://www.google.com/?tracking=EMAIL_DEPARTMENT&code=EMAIL_DEPARTMENT`

Currently, I am simple doing the following:

```
%%[
SET @url = "http://www.google.com/"
SET @trackingCode = "EMAIL_DEPARTMENT" 
SET @tracking = concat("?tracking=", @trackingCode)
SET @LINK1 = concat(@url,@trackingCode)
]%%
```

`<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@LINK1)=%%">Buy Today</a>`

The problem with my current solution is that I have to change the code for each link.

I would like a solution where I can simple do this:

`<a href="http://www.google.com">Buy Today</a>`

And AMPscript would return this:

`http://www.google.com/?tracking=EMAIL_DEPARTMENT&code=EMAIL_DEPARTMENT`

Any suggestions would be really appreciated? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Web Analytics Connector](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/) (WAC) and `Additional Email Attributes` to accomplish this without any scripting.

You can give SFMC Support the parameter strings and the personalization string (or AMPScript variable) values and the process will add them to all of your URLs automatically.

The WAC string would be something like this:

```
&tracking=EMAIL_DEPARTMENT&code=%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%
```

The Additional Email Attributes are enabled by SFMC Support. The values are set in an input box on the Email Properties page.

Comment: Thanks! We have been hardcoding the tracking source codes all this time, as you could imagine this manual process takes some time.